# Why Angular async pipe doesn't work with getter which returns Promise

Tags: javascript, angular

Component .ts

```
get user(): Promise<string> {
 //method returns the promise
return getCurrentUser();
  }
```

Component .html

```
<p>{{ user | async }}</p>
```

the expression above returns just an empty string in html

Why? What's the problem?

Comment: This could possibly be because you don't have a value for the promise. Try following https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe to see if your component is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like:

Set a variable in ts class

`public user: User;`

in ngOnInit or other moment call the function that gets that user:

```
async fetchUser(): void {
 this.user = await getCurrentUser();
}
```

in the html only needed the following:
`<p>{{ user }}</p>`

Since the variables are reactive, as soon the function updates the value of user, in the html will be updated.

You could also use observable as the official documentation uses. (the comment you got in the question)

Comment: Yeah i tried this solution and it works fine. Thanks. I'm just curious why async pipe doesn't work with getter which returns promise 